# Implicit Intent - java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method on a null object reference

Tags: android, kotlin, android-implicit-intent

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.app.ActivityThread$ApplicationThread android.app.ActivityThread.getApplicationThread()' on a null object reference
```

I am getting this error when I am trying to open a link with implicit intent. I am calling `openUrl(url: String)` in `Settings.kt` activity from it's adapter class `SettingsAdapter.kt` through a `setOnClcikListener` on a ImageView.

**SettingsAdapter.kt** Class

```
private val settings = Settings()
youtubeLink.setOnClickListener {
            val url = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i-0FtaAadeM"
            settings.openUrl(url)
        }
```

**Settings.kt** Activity

```
fun openUrl(url: String) {
        val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse(url))
        startActivity(intent)
    }
```

Comment: What are you doing exactly? Creating a class object and calling its function?

Comment: Yes. I've created an object of Settings.kt activity in it's adapter class

Comment: You should never create an object of Activity yourself . OS handles it for you . Please read about `Activity` first .

Comment: @AdityaGupta This is wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are following wrong approach. You can do this in two ways.

1. You can directly call code snippet in your adapter

   ```
     youtubeLink.setOnClickListener {
        val url = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i-0FtaAadeM"
        val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse(url))
        context.startActivity(intent)
    }
   ```
2. You can create a callback in your adapter and implement in your activity

   ```
    private OnSettingsListener listener;

   void setOnSttingListener(OnSettingsListener listener){
     this.listener = listener;
   }

   youtubeLink.setOnClickListener {
        val url = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i-0FtaAadeM"
        listener.onSettingClick(url);
    }

   interface OnSettingsListener {  
     void onSettingClick(String url);     
   }
   ```

   In your activity, implement this listener

   ```
    Settings implements SettingsAdapter.OnSettingsListener {

    @Override
    public void onSettingClick(String url) {
     openUrl(url)
   }
   }
   ```

Comment: Yeah. I got it now, I was following the first approach before but I haven't wrapped the startActivity() with context so I was getting an error